# $F(x)+G(y)= e^{x+y}?$

Tags: functions, exponential-function

Are there functions $F(x)$, $G(y)$, such that
 $F(x)+G(y)=e^{x+y}$ , where $x,y$ are real numbers? I have been trying all elementary functions, and have no clues on what else I could do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is another solution. Applying $\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial x \partial y}$ to the both sides of $F(x)+G(y)=e^{x+y}$, we have $0=e^{x+y}$. This never holds. Therefore the functions you want do not exist.

Answer (score 10):

No such $F$ and $G$ exist.

The fact that $F(0) + G(y) = e^{y}$ for all real $y$ would imply $G(y) = e^{y} - F(0)$.

Similarly, $F(x) = e^{x} - G(0)$ for all real $x$. No matter how $F(0)$ and $G(0)$ are chosen, you're sunk.

Answer (score 4):

If that were the case, you would have for all $y$, $$F(1) - F(0)=F(1)+G(y) -(F(0)+G(y)) = e^{1+y}-e^y=e^y(e-1),$$ so $e^{y}(e-1)$ would be constant.

---

Motivation: Initially I thought of taking a partial derivative, but with more generality, it suffices to take a difference $f(0+1,y) -f(0,y)$.

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't the middle equality be $-G(y)+e^{1+y}-(-G(y)+e^y)$ ? Maybe it's equivalent...

Comment: @pbs: Well it would equivalent, but there would be no reason to have the expression in your comment as far as I can see.  Is there an equals sign you don't follow?  (The first equation is probably best read right to left, the second equation follows from the hypothesis.)

Comment: Yes, the way it is written confused me for a moment. However, on expanding the middle equality now I clearly see it does equal $F(1)-F(0)$. I was looking at what you had written from a different perspective - I was trying to construct the middle equality from the first by rearranging the original equation. Sorted now I see clearly what's happing - that "old trick" of adding something and then taking it away, so yes maybe best read right to left. +1 for your answer!